# How to fix MikTex missing packages?

Tags: pdftex, tex-core

I had to reinstall my system OS last week. (Windows 10)
I had been using Windows 7 and MikTex.
I created my file with TexMaker and before my OS install the preview compiled fine
Now with a brand new install of everything I'm seeing errors that don't make sense when it was working before.

The author of TexMaker suggests there is a problem with the MikTex install

I don't know how to figure out what's missing, would appreciate some help in learning how to track down the problem.

The file (with the beginning and end of the document)

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Section 1.2 - Distance Formula}
\newline \textbf{Problems}
\newline \textbf{A}
\newline \textit{In problems 1-8, find the distance between the given points}
\\
\newline 1. $A=(1,-3), B=(2,5)$ $\color{blue} => x_1=1, x_2=2$, $\color{green}y_1=-3, y_2=5 $\\
\textbf{\underline {Solution}:}\\
\newline$\overline{AB}=\sqrt{(2-1)^2+(5-(-3))^2}=\sqrt{(1)^2+(5+3)^2}=\sqrt{1^2+8^2}=\sqrt{1+64}=\sqrt{65}$\\
\newline 2. $A=(4,13), B=(-1,5)$ $\color{blue} => x_1 =4, x_2=-1$, $\color{green}y_1=13, y_2=5 $\\
\textbf{\underline {Solution}:}\\
\newline$\overline{AB}=\sqrt{(-1-4)^2+(13-5)^2}=\sqrt{(-5)^2+(8)^2}=\sqrt{25+64}=\sqrt{89}$\\
\newline 3. $A=(3, -2), B=(3, -4)$ $\color{blue} => x_1 =3, x_2=-2$, $\color{green}y_1=3, y_2=-4 $\\
\textbf{\underline {Solution}:}\\
\newline$\overline{AB}=\sqrt{(-2-3)^2 + (-4-3)^2}=\sqrt{(-5)^2+(-7)^2}=\sqrt{25+49}=\sqrt{74}$\\
\newline 4. $A=(-5, 1), B=(0, -10)$ $\color{blue} => x_1=-5, x_2=0$, $\color{green}y_1=1, y_2=-10 $\\
\textbf{\underline {Solution}:}\\
\newline$\overline{AB}=\sqrt{(0-(-5))^2+(-10-1)^2}=\sqrt{(0+5)^2+(-11)^2}=\sqrt{5^2+(-11)^2}=\sqrt{25+121}=\sqrt{146}$\\
\newline 5. $A=(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}), B=(\frac{-5}{2}, 2)$ $\color{blue} => x_1=\frac{1}{2}, x_2=\frac{-5}{2}$, $\color{green}y_1=\frac{3}{2}, y_2=2 $\\
\textbf{\underline {Solution}:}\\
\newline$\overline{AB}=\sqrt{(\frac{-5}{2}-\frac{1}{2})^2+(2-\frac{3}{2})^2}=\sqrt{(\frac{-6}{2})^2+(\frac{4}{2}-\frac{3}{2})^2}=\sqrt{(-3)^2+(\frac{1}{2})^2}=\sqrt{9+\frac{1}{4}}=\sqrt{\frac{36}{4}+\frac{1}{4}}=\sqrt{\frac{37}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{37}}{2}$\\
\newline 6. $A=(\frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{3}), B=(\frac{-4}{3}, \frac{4}{3})$ $\color{blue} => x_1=\frac{2}{3}, x_2=\frac{-4}{3}$, $\color{green}y_1=\frac{1}{3}, y_2=\frac{4}{3} $\\
\textbf{\underline {Solution}:}\\
\newline$\overline{AB}=\sqrt{(\frac{-4}{3}-\frac{2}{3})^2+(\frac{4}{3}-\frac{1}{3})^2}=\sqrt{(\frac{-6}{3})^2+(\frac{3}{3})^2}=\sqrt{(-2)^2+(1)^2}=\sqrt{4+1}=\sqrt{5}$\\
\newline 7. $A=(\sqrt{2}, 1), B=(2\sqrt{2}, 3)$ $\color{blue} => x_1=\sqrt{2}, x_2=2$, $\color{green}y_1=1, y_2=\sqrt{2} $\\
\textbf{\underline {Solution}:}\\
\newline$\overline{AB}=\sqrt{(2\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2})^2+(3-1)^2}=\sqrt{(\sqrt{2})^2+(2)^2}=\sqrt{2+4}=\sqrt{6}$\\
\newline 8. $A=(\sqrt{3}, -\sqrt{2}), B=(-3\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{2})$ $\color{blue} => x_1=\sqrt{3}, x_2=-3\sqrt{3}$, $\color{green}y_1=13, y_2= $\\
\textbf{\underline {Solution}:}\\
\newline$\overline{AB}=\sqrt{(-3\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{3})^2+(\sqrt{2}-(-\sqrt{2}))^2}=\sqrt{(-4\sqrt{3})^2+(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{(-4\sqrt{3})^2+(2\sqrt{2})}=\sqrt{(-4)^2(\sqrt{3})^2+(2)^2(\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{(16)(3)+(4)(2)}=\sqrt{48+8}=\sqrt{56}$\\
\\
\newline \textit{In Problems 9-14, determine whether the three given points are collinear}
\begin{quote}
[Given 3 points A, B, C, these points are collinear if $\overline{AC}=\overline{AB}+\overline{BC}$ or $\overline{AC}=\overline{BC}-\overline{AB}$]
\end{quote}
9. $A=(2, 1), B=(4, 3), C=(-1, -2)$\\
\textbf{\underline {Solution}:}\\
\newline $\overline{AB} =\sqrt{(4-2)^2+(3-1)^2}=\sqrt{(2)^2+(2)^2}=\sqrt{4+4}=\sqrt{8}=2\sqrt{2}$
\newline $\overline{BC} =\sqrt{(-1-4)^2+(-2-3)^2}=\sqrt{(-5)^2+(-5)^2}=\sqrt{25+25}=\sqrt{50}=\sqrt{25}\sqrt{2}=5\sqrt{2}$
\newline $\overline{AC} =\sqrt{(-1-2))^2+(-2-1)^2}=\sqrt{(-3)^2+(-3)^2}=\sqrt{9+9}=\sqrt{18}=\sqrt{9}\sqrt{2}=3\sqrt{2}$
\\
\newline 10. $A=(3, 2), B=(4, 6), C=(0, -8)$\\
\textbf{\underline {Solution}:}\\
\newline $\overline{AB} =\sqrt{(4-3)^2+(6-2)^2}=\sqrt{(1)^2+(4)^2}=\sqrt{1+16}=\sqrt{17}$
\newline $\overline{BC} =\sqrt{(0-4)^2+(-8-6)^2}=\sqrt{(-4)^2+(-14)^2}=\sqrt{16+196}=\sqrt{212}=\sqrt{4}\sqrt{53}=2\sqrt{53}$
\newline $\overline{AC} =\sqrt{(0-3)^2+(-8-2)^2}=\sqrt{(-3)^2+(-10)^2}=\sqrt{9+100}=\sqrt{109}$
\\
\newline 11. A=$(-2, 3), B=(7, -2), C=(2, 5)$\\
\textbf{\underline {Solution}:}\\
\newline $\overline{AB} =\sqrt{(7-(-2))^2+(-2-3)^2}=\sqrt{(7+2)^2+(-5)^2}=\sqrt{9^2+25}=\sqrt{81+25}=\sqrt{106}=\sqrt{4}\sqrt{26}=2\sqrt{26}$
\newline $\overline{BC} =\sqrt{(2-7)^2+(5-(-2))^2}=\sqrt{(-5)^2+(5+2)^2}=\sqrt{25+7^2}=\sqrt{25+49}=\sqrt{74}$
\newline $\overline{AC} =\sqrt{(2-(-2))^2+(5-3)^2}=\sqrt{(2+2)^2+(2)^2}=\sqrt{4^2+4}=\sqrt{16+4}=\sqrt{20}=\sqrt{4}\sqrt{5}=2\sqrt{5}$
\\
\newline 12. A=$(2, -1), B=(-1, 4), C=(5, -6)$\\
\textbf{\underline {Solution}:}\\
\newline $\overline{AB} =\sqrt{(-1-2)^2+(4-(-1))^2}=\sqrt{(-3)^2+(4+1)^2}=\sqrt{9+(5)^2}=\sqrt{9+25}=\sqrt{34}$
\newline $\overline{BC} =\sqrt{(5-(-1))^2+(-6-4)^2}=\sqrt{(5+1)^2+(-10)^2}=\sqrt{(6)^2+100}==\sqrt{36+100}=\sqrt{136}=4\sqrt{34}$
\newline $\overline{AC} =\sqrt{(5-2)^2+(-6-(-1))^2}=\sqrt{(3)^2+(-6+1)^2}=\sqrt{9+(-5)^2}=\sqrt{9+25}=\sqrt{34}$
\\
\newline 13. A=$(1, -1), B=(3, 3), C=(0, -3)$\\
\textbf{\underline {Solution}:}\\
\newline $\overline{AB} =\sqrt{(3-1)^2+(3-(-1))^2}=\sqrt{(2)^2+(3+1)^2}=\sqrt{(2)^2+(4)^2}=\sqrt{4+16}=\sqrt{20}=\sqrt{4}\sqrt{5}=2\sqrt{5}$
\newline $\overline{BC} =\sqrt{(0-3)^2+(-3-3)^2}=\sqrt{(-3)^2+(-6)^2}=\sqrt{9+36}=\sqrt{45}=\sqrt{9}\sqrt{5}=3\sqrt{5}$
\newline $\overline{AC} =\sqrt{(0-1)^2+(-3-(-1))^2}=\sqrt{(-1)^2+(-3+1)^2}=\sqrt{1+(-2)^2}=\sqrt{1+4}=\sqrt{5}$
\\
\newline 14. A=$(1, \sqrt{2}), B=(4, 3\sqrt{2}), C=(10, 6\sqrt{2})$\\
\textbf{\underline {Solution}:}\\
\newline $\overline{AB} =\sqrt{(4-1)^2+(3\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{(3)^2+(2\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{9+(2)^2)(\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{9+(4)(2)}=\sqrt{9+8}=\sqrt{17}$
\newline $\overline{BC} =\sqrt{(10-4)^2+(6\sqrt{2}-3\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{(6)^2+(3\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{36+(3)^2(\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{36+(9)(2)}=\sqrt{36+18}=\sqrt{54}$
\newline $\overline{AC} =\sqrt{(10-1)^2+(6\sqrt{2}-3\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{(9)^2+(3\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{81+(3)^2(\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{81+(9)(2)}=\sqrt{81+18}=\sqrt{99}=\sqrt{9}\sqrt{11}=3\sqrt{11}$
\\
\newline \textit{In Problems 15-18, determine whether the three given points are the vertices of a right triangle}
\begin{quote}
[Given 3 points A, B, C, these points create a triangle if $\overline{AC} < \overline{AB}+\overline{BC}$]
\end{quote}

29. Show that a triangle with vertices $(x1, y1)$, $(x2,y2)$, $(x3, y3)$ has area 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{vmatrix}
 x_1y_2 +x_2y_3 +x_3y_1 - x_1y_3 -x_2y_1 -x_3y_2
\end{vmatrix}
 = 
 \begin{vmatrix}
 \frac{1}{2}
 \begin{vmatrix}
 x_1 & y_1 & 1\\
 x_2 & y_2 & 1\\
 x_3 & y_3 & 1
 \end{vmatrix}
 \end{vmatrix}
\end{align}
[Hint: Consider the rectangle with sides parallel to the coordinate axes and containing the vertices of the triangle.]

30. Prove analytically that if the diagonals of a parallelogram are equal, then the parallelogram is a rectangle.\\
[Hint: Place the axes as shown in fig 1.10 and show that $\overflow{AC} = \overflow{BD}$ implies that $A$ is the origin]

31. Prove analytically that the sum of the lengths of two sides of a triangle is greater than the length of the third side.


\end{document}
```

The log output

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.10) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.10.6)  6 OCT 2021 14:27
entering extended mode
**./Section1.2_Problems.tex
(Section1.2_Problems.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-08-27>
(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count182
\c@section=\count183
\c@subsection=\count184
\c@subsubsection=\count185
\c@paragraph=\count186
\c@subparagraph=\count187
\c@figure=\count188
\c@table=\count189
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks16
\inpenc@posthook=\toks17
)
(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2021/04/20 v2.17j AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip49

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks18
\ex@=\dimen139
))
(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen140
)
(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count190
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count191
\leftroot@=\count192
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count193
\DOTSCASE@=\count194
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box50
\strutbox@=\box51
\big@size=\dimen141
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count195
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count196
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count197
\dspbrk@lvl=\count198
\tag@help=\toks19
\row@=\count199
\column@=\count266
\maxfields@=\count267
\andhelp@=\toks20
\eqnshift@=\dimen142
\alignsep@=\dimen143
\tagshift@=\dimen144
\tagwidth@=\dimen145
\totwidth@=\dimen146
\lineht@=\dimen147
\@envbody=\toks21
\multlinegap=\skip50
\multlinetaggap=\skip51
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks22
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
)
(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
)
(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2020/12/05 v1.2c Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks23
)
(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen148
\Gin@req@width=\dimen149
)
(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count268
\Gm@cntv=\count269
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count270
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen150
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen151
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen152
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen153
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen154
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen155
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen156
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen157
\Gm@dimlist=\toks24

(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.cfg))
(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-08-04 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count271
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box52
)
(Section1.2_Problems.aux)
\openout1 = `Section1.2_Problems.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.

(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count272
\scratchdimen=\dimen158
\scratchbox=\box53
\nofMPsegments=\count273
\nofMParguments=\count274
\everyMPshowfont=\toks25
\MPscratchCnt=\count275
\MPscratchDim=\dimen159
\MPnumerator=\count276
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count277
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks26
) (C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: letterpaper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(56.9055pt, 500.484pt, 56.9055pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(56.9055pt, 681.15898pt, 56.9055pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=500.484pt
* \textheight=681.15898pt
* \oddsidemargin=-15.36449pt
* \evensidemargin=-15.36449pt
* \topmargin=-52.36449pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=65.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 15.

(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 15.


(C:\Applications\Editors\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--41

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--41

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--41

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--41

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--41

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--41

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--41

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--41

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--41

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--41

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--41

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--41

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--41

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--41

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--41

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--41

 []


Overfull \hbox (46.03345pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--41
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 = [] = [] = [] = [] =
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--41

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--41

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 44--81

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 44--81

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 44--81

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 44--81

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 44--81

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 44--81

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 44--81

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 44--81

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 44--81

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 44--81

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 44--81

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 44--81

 []

[1

{C:/Users/kingram/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 84--107

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 84--107

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 84--107

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 84--107

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 84--107

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 84--107

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 84--107

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 84--107

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 84--107

 []

[2]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 108--167

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 108--167

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 108--167

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 108--167

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 108--167

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 108--167

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 108--167

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 108--167

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 108--167

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 108--167

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 108--167

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 108--167

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 108--167

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 108--167

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 108--167

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 108--167

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 108--167

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 108--167

 []

[3]
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   H
l.185 ...flow{BD}$ implies that $A$ is the origin]
                                                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   H
l.185 ...flow{BD}$ implies that $A$ is the origin]
                                                  
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \overflow 
                          
l.185 ...flow{BD}$ implies that $A$ is the origin]
                                                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...ow that $\overflow {AC} = \overflow 
                                                  {BD}$ implies that $A$ is ...
l.185 ...flow{BD}$ implies that $A$ is the origin]
                                                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 184--186

 []

[4] (Section1.2_Problems.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3376 strings out of 478927
 45318 string characters out of 2859123
 389184 words of memory out of 3000000
 21221 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 405783 words of font info for 37 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 57i,20n,66p,283b,230s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
<C:/Applications/Editors/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/publ
ic/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><C:/Applications/Editors/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/am
sfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb><C:/Applications/Editors/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfont
s/cm/cmmi10.pfb><C:/Applications/Editors/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmr10.pfb><C:/Applications/Editors/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.p
fb><C:/Applications/Editors/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb><C
:/Applications/Editors/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7.pfb><C:/Appl
ications/Editors/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb><C:/Applicati
ons/Editors/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msam10.pfb>
Output written on W:\PROJECTS\math\analyticgeometry\build\Section1.2_Problems.p
df (4 pages, 127594 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 60 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: this doesn't look like an install problem but some problem  with your code. Make a complete, small example so that one test your issue. But in case there is a missing package error earlier: simply install it with the miktex console.

Comment: It was compiling without problems last week. Nothing has changed other than installing the latest MikTex.

Comment: Installing the lastest miktex probably means that a number of packages changes. That is not "nothing". If you want help, provide an example so that someone can debug it. Or show at least the real log-file, the truncated error messages are useless.

Comment: Ok. You're right that's not "nothing".

Comment: What symbol should be `\overflow{AC}`? Command `\overflow` is unknown ...

Comment: also please don't use external links, your question is archived here forever and will not make sense if those links change. You can add the error message as a code block to your question. as Mench says `\overflow` being undefined seems unrelated to the miktex update.

Comment: unrelated to the error but why all the `\newline` and `\\ `  ? every one of them is generating warning that the badness is 10000 (ie the output has _maximum_ badness)

Comment: Still figuring out how to build the file, so the obvious misuse is due to me being a novice at this. I don't yet know another way to create a new line.

Comment: I just noticed \overflow. That should be \overline

Comment: @UlrikeFischerOP has had some messages with the TexMaker "author": _the author of TexMaker suggests there is a problem with the MikTex install_. But I think the package problem was a assumption by the OP.

Comment: Your problem is the \\ followed by [H on the next line..Put an empty brace group between both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error is due to this in your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
... rectangle.\\
[Hint:... ]

\end{document}
```

LaTeX assumes the the bracket `[` starts the optional argument of `\\` and so looks for a number. Add for example an empty brace group to stop this `\\{}`.

And don't use so many `\\`, you get tons of underfull box messages in your code (and your output looks rather ugly):

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 39--70

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 39--70

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 39--70

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 39--70

 []
```

Use empty lines to separate paragraphs, or use a list.

Comment: Thanks. I followed these tips and was able to figure out what went wrong.
I didn't realize that simply having a blank line was the proper way to create newlines. It's all much cleaner now, and no errors.